# Launching a Java applet from BlazeDS

Tags: java, applet, blazeds

I wanted to know if it was possible to launch an Applet from BlazeDS?

Answer (score 0):

BlazeDS is running on the server side - it consists from several jar files which can be integrated in any application running inside a servlet container. So no it is not possible.